# I want to remove a letter from all the elements in an array and replace it with a string using PHP.

Tags: php

```
$numbers = array("18339993993","18303839303");
foreach($numbers as $number) {
    $number = explode(",", $number);
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($number); $i++) {
        $number = substr($number,1, 10);
        echo $number;
}
```

please i want to remove the first number in every element in the array and replace it with "999" to all the elements in the array.

```
I want my output to be like this for each element in the array:

$output[0] = "9998339993993"
$output[1] = "9998303839303"
```

Comment: why are you doing that explode()? There are NO `,` in either of the numbers in your array.

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you:

(Here I go through every element of the array with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Then I return each element with `999` at the start plus the original value with an offset of 1 which I get with [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php))

```
<?php

    $numbers = array("18339993993","18303839303");
    $numbers = array_map(function($v){
        return "999" . substr($v, 1);
    }, $numbers);
    print_r($numbers);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 9998339993993 [1] => 9998303839303 )
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. it works for only the first item in the array

Comment: please my array looks like this: 
array ( 18339993993,18303839303, 18303811303 );

Comment: @user3197193 Also works, see here: http://3v4l.org/fDcG9 All 3 elements got the 999 at the start. Are you sure you copied my **full** code?

Comment: its still not working. i just checked my javascript console. this is the array. $numbers = array("18339993993,18303839303,18398989283");

Comment: @user3197193 *javascript* Are you programming JS? Also add error reporting at the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` and tell us if you get any. Please make sure you show us all your code! Also please post how you use my code!

Comment: @Rizier123 - I deleted my answer after I noticed you beat me to the array_map answer.  But, one thing you should change is the use of double-quotes.  I think single quotes will perform better.

Comment: this is the result i get
$output =  Array ( [0] => 9998339993993,18303839303 );

Comment: @user3197193 Please answer all my questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988837/i-want-to-remove-a-letter-from-all-the-elements-in-an-array-and-replace-it-with/28988894?noredirect=1#comment46227398_28988894 So that I'm able to help you

Comment: This works 100% correctly for me - using PHP that is!

Comment: am using jquery to send to the php file. the problem is my php code. i guess its because my array is stored as a string.
$number = array("18339993993,18303839303,18398989283");

Comment: @user3197193 You have shown us now already 3 different arrays! 1. `$numbers = array("18339993993","18303839303");` 2. `array ( 18339993993,18303839303, 18303811303 );` 3. `$number = array("18339993993,18303839303,18398989283");` Which array do you have now? Or do they change on every refresh? (BTW: You still didn't answered all my questions for my second last comment)

Comment: this is my initial array:
$number = array("18339993993,18303839303,18398989283");

Comment: @user3197193 Well this a completely different array than in your question! (Add this line: `$numbers = explode(",", $numbers[0]);` right after your initial array)

Comment: @Rizier123 it works. thank you very much. i so so so love Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Closer to the code in the question:

```
<?php
  $numbers = array("18339993993","18303839303");
  $numbers_after = array();
  foreach ($numbers as $number){
    $number = "999" . substr($number, 1);
    array_push($numbers_after, $number);
  }
  print_r ($numbers_after);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there was no regex solution:

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/^\d/', '999', $numbers);
```

Easy as that.

Comment: Didn't thought about regex, I think you have the easiest answer! :D