# Add character before a variable

Tags: php, variables, character

I need to add a character before the number is posted

```
    $phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
```

if the user_phone was 123456789, i need it to get converted to 0123456789 before the number is posted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29019003/3933332 <- I think this one should work for you

Comment: can you please show me in an example i'm still a beginner

Comment: For sure here is an example: http://3v4l.org/thqss (<- Just modified it a little bit, and if it helped you can leave an upV to the posted answer above)

Comment: If you really need it altered before it is posted you will need to write some Javascript into the form. But this isn't necessary: you can do it all on receipt, in the PHP code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP uses the `.` character for string concatenation.
You could just concatenate it:

```
$user_phone = '123456789';
$user_phone = '0'.$user_phone;
$_POST['user_phone'] = $user_phone;
```